# How would I use riverpod code generation to create this StateNotifierProvider?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

This manually constructed StateNotifier Provider works in Flutter. However, I cannot figure out how to use code gen to make this same thing. Any ideas?

```
class SessionProvider extends StateNotifier<Session> {
  final Ref ref;

  final sessionManager = singleton<ApiClient>().sessionManager;
  final client = singleton<ApiClient>().client;

  SessionProvider(this.ref, Session initial) : super(initial) {
    init();
  }

  init() {
    updateUser();
  }

  updateUser() async {
    final user = sessionManager.signedInUser;
    // final profile = await client.profile.me();
    state = state.copyWith(
      user: user,
    );
  }
}
```

Nothing has even come close.

Answer (score 1):

Riverpod code generator won't generate `StateNotifier` and its provider. Please note that along with Riverpod 2.0, new classes were introduced: `Notifier` / `AsyncNotifer`.
`StateNotifier` is now discouraged in favor of those new APIs.

See: [From `StateNotifier`](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/from_state_notifier).

The page shows how you can achieve similar thing with `Notifier`, to make the migration process from `StateNotifier` easy (see [this section](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/from_state_notifier#from-stateprovider)). Basically, define a `state` setter and an `update` method that works similarly to the ones on `StateNotifier`.

So you can define a class like this:

```dart
@riverpod
class SessionNotifier extends _$SessionNotifier {
  @override
  int build() => Session(); // This should be the value you previously passed to `initial`

  @override
  set state(Session newState) => super.state = newState;
  update(Session Function(int state) cb) => state = cb(state);
}
```

**Edit:** On a side note, if you're using `StateNotifier`, chances are you already use methods to modify the state, so migrating to `Notifier` will mostly about changing the way you initialize the state. The above code is more relevant if you're migrating from `StateProvider`.